# Retagging docker image

Tags: git, docker, package, gitlab, artifact

Imagine a pipeline that's conditioned in the following way:
Change-branch:

---

*|Package| -> |Test|*

---

When that change has been proven worthy, it should be merged into the master branch, which has a slightly different pipeline due to the usage of the `only` and `except` keywords:

```
  only:
- master
```

or

```
  except:
- master
```

The master-branche's pipeline would look like this:

---

*|retag&push| -> |release|*

---

The retag here is very important, as we don't want to rebuild an image (package) we have validated during our MR, as it might not be the exact same image as the one we tested so diligently.

The problem is that in gitlab, there is no clear way of knowing which image it should retag.
In the `|Package|`-job we use the git-commit and git-branch as tags for the package but when the pipeline is running for master, there doesn't seem to be a proper way to reliably determine the image tag that has to be re-tagged to, for example: `latest`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the change has been tested on a different branch, not `master`. So if you have an image that has been built based off a branch other than master then you are releasing stuff from non master branch. The ideal scenario would be to test the builds only from master branch.

Let me share the strategy used in our company. Developers fork the repo, make changes, commit to their private repos and make Pull Requests (PRs) to the primary repo. The changes in the PR are validated automatically by drone. Once the tests pass, we merge the changes into the primary repo's master branch. We then create a release candidate tag (say `v2.0.0-rc1`) on the primary repo's master branch. Our QA team has setup on-tag jenkins builds for this repo/branch. Once the automation tests pass, the tag `v2.0.0-rc1` is used for retagging to `latest`. Currently this step is done manually in our case as we want to have manual intervention, but can be automated completely.

Comment: I understand the solution, and it would fix our problem. The issue I'm having with this solution is that it goes against policy to merge smt into master that isn't deployed to production (and branches are aptly considered staging environment material)